# Recurrence meaning

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning, sentence-meaning

In a book I'm reading, there is a way to use recurrence as follows:

> Obviously, astronauts have to be in exceptionally good physical
>   condition and to have as low a risk of developing health problems
>   as possible. Minor issues could disqualify astronaut hopefuls— for
>   example, one occurrence of kidney stones could disqualify you from
>   flying in space. NASA can’t risk a **recurrence** that would incapacitate
>   an astronaut or require a costly early return.

My question is: what does **recurrence** here mean? Does it mean that NASA has made a mistake [in choosing an astronaut with bad condition] and now they have to prevent that happens again (recurrence)?

Comment: It means they can't risk the problem happening again. This meaning should be discoverable in a dictionary.

Comment: NASA can’t risk a recurrence (of known health problems). *recurrence* refers to "risk of developing health problems".

Answer (score 2):

The preceding clause provides the context you need.   We're given the example of one occurrence of kidney stones in a potential astronaut.   A recurrence of kidney stones could incapacitate such an astronaut or require a costly early return.   The kidney stones themselves are just one example of the kind of minor issues for which NASA has reason to disqualify astronaut hopefuls.

Answer (score 0):

The prefix 're' has several uses, one of those is to indicate that something has happened again [Oxford Dict - re](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/re-). So something can 'occur' once, or re-occur more than once.  However, we don't actually say 're-occur' we blend the two parts into a single word, i.e. recur.